# Filter Categories in meta box for CPTs

Tags: categories, filters, admin

Working with a custom post type in Wordpress, I would like to use the categories. So I added the categories to the cpt. No problems here.

But, when adding or editing cpt items, I would like to filter the categories they can choose from.

Currently it shows all categories. But I want to show only specific categories (or categories below a specific parent category).

FYI: A special taxonomy for the cpt is not an option in my use case.

I cannot find a filter / action I could use to filter all categories shown on a edit page for a specific CPT.

**Example of the situation**

A custom-post-type named 'Books'. Normal Wordpress categories: 'category A', 'category B', 'subcategory A-1', 'subcategory A-2'

When editing a 'Book', I want the category select box to show: 'subcategory A-1', 'subcategory A-2'. And omit all other categories.

**All help is appreciated.**

Comment: Can I ask WHY a custom taxonomy is not an option?

Comment: hi @TonyDjukic, some of the categories is for both cpt's and posts. But some i want them filtered for some CPT's and not for posts. Thanks for thinking with me.

Comment: Best logic I can think of is to create a settings screen in your plugin/theme where you “exclude” categories using a multi-select (Select2)... then suppress the default categories metabox in the CPT and instead put in your own metabox that displays categories that are NOT listed as excluded from the CPT in the theme/plugin settings.

Comment: "some of the categories is for both cpt's and posts. But some i want them filtered for some CPT's and not for posts." Very interesting! What about doing the reverse - setup a custom taxonomy and make it available to Posts as well as your CPT. Then only add in the custom taxonomy those you want available to CPTs, put all others in the normal Categories which will by default be available to Posts.

Comment: TonyDjukic and Trisha: two really good suggestions. Still hoping for that one filter to fix it the 'normal' way. But both your ideas are great! Appreciate it big time!